# iOS How to confirm 'Delete' for UIPreviewActions on images from CollectionView

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, 3dtouch

Similar to Apple's Photo App, I'm using peek and pop on a collectionView of images.  When you peek on a cell, you are shown the image on a PhotoViewController that just shows that image in an imageView. Apple provides 4 different preview actions:  Copy, Share, Favourite, Delete.  If the user hits 'Delete', the preview actions are updated to: Delete and Cancel. The peek image still shows.

In my own code, I can setup the preview actions and delete the photo but am not able to confirm the deletion before it occurs.  I also cannot figure out how to keep the peek view open (or reopen it) with the new preview actions of Delete or Cancel.

Question:  How can I get the user to confirm the deletion before it happens?

I tried putting a UIAlertController inside the UIPreviewAction but get a warning: "Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!"  I tried a few alternatives such as using keyWindow to present the alertController but couldn't get that to work quickly.  I assuming I can set another notification to the collection view so that when the peek closes with a 'Delete', an alert controller appears asking the user to confirm the deletion but by that stage the image no longer appears.

Any suggestions?  Here are the alternatives I've used so far.

```
UIPreviewAction *delete = [UIPreviewAction actionWithTitle:@"Delete" style:UIPreviewActionStyleDestructive handler:^(UIPreviewAction * _Nonnull action, UIViewController * _Nonnull previewViewController)
    { 

//create alertController
...

// 1. present alertController:  
[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];

// 2. Alternatively tried to present alertController using keyWindow         
UIViewController *top = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
[top presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion: nil];

//3. notify the presenting view controller that the user has deleted the image and set up an alert to occur after the peek view closes.

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"deleteAlert" object:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it is an old questions, but the solution is quite easy, so posting it here!

**Swift 3**

```
        let closeTabAction = UIPreviewAction(title: "Close Tab", style: .destructive, handler: { (action, viewController) in
            //this is confirmation action
        })

        let closeTabCancelAction = UIPreviewAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: { (action, viewController) in
            //cancel action, don't need anything here
        })


        //UIPreviewActionGroup, this is the main action
        let closeTabGroup = UIPreviewActionGroup(title: "Close Tab", style: .destructive, actions: [closeTabAction, closeTabCancelAction])

        return [closeTabGroup]
```

Basically, you just need to use the UIPreviewActionGroup to create submenus. [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipreviewactiongroup)